# Set value in html input not work

Tags: javascript, html, yui

i wanted to fill the first form on [yahoo registration](https://edit.yahoo.com/registration?) automatically.
for example when i click and choose inspect element on this page and change firstname input from

```
<input type="text" title="First Name" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="" size="32" maxlength="32" class="fieldValInit" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" tabindex="1">
```

to

```
<input type="text" title="First Name" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="salam" size="32" maxlength="32" class="" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" tabindex="1">
```

I do not see any changes on the page. Why?

Comment: the scenario mentioned by you, works for me. I can able to edit the HTML from inspect element and can modify the value. I have verifed with firebug, Chrome and IE. Check with your browser versions. To set the value of an element dynamically, then use the below javascript document.getElementById('FirstName').value = "salam";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the placeholder you don't see the change. You can use:

```
document.getElementById('firstname').value = 'foo';
```

in the browser's console and you'll see the first name changed to `foo`.

Answer (score -3):

You cannot change the element of HTML directly from the browser unless you download the whole web page to your computer and edit the HTML code.

You should use JavaScript (F12 in the browser -> Console)

(e.g. input  **document.getElementById('firstname').value = 'foo';** )

Then you can it reflects the web page instantly